# Elance / freelancer.com or the client - who is important for tax reasons?

Tags: freelance-websites, taxes, invoices

I am currently facing the following situation:

- I have a lot of projects going on freelancer.com / elance
- I do payments to freelancer thru these sites
- these sites in turn take the money from my paypal / creditcard or bank account, so these sites appear also on creditcard slips / bank transaction protocols

As my tax is due now, I am unsure, who is the actual invoicer in terms of tax.

Each site is charging fees, which occur on the creditcard slips, as well as the costs for the project.

So, the question is, what would I need to satisfy the tax (am based in Germany).

Does anyone have experience with that?

Comment: What kind of tax are you referring to? Income tax? Sales tax?

Comment: This is about income tax accounting. Any transaction that goes thru bank account or CC must be documented.
My direct transaction partner in this case is the freelancer sites, as they also manage the payments and draft the funds + fees for the various jobs..

So, while I can document this ok, Im wondering if I might also require direct invoices from the developers as well...

Answer (score 3):

I am not an accountant and I am not familiar with tax law in Germany but:

As long as freelancer.com / elance.com properly account for any VAT that is being charged on the invoices, then their invoices can likely be used.

For example, elance.com does seem to have this capability for some countries including Germany but you may need to set this up in your account. For details see: http://help.elance.com/hc/en-us/articles/203735283-How-do-I-use-VAT-on-Elance-

As with any tax or legal question, you should really be checking with someone who is professionally qualified to answer and who is familiar with the tax and legal system in your local area.